# Как скомпилить несколько .sass файлов с mix.sass()?

Tags: sass, laravel-mix

Есть такая структура папки `./src/scss/`:

```
--> scss
----> root.scss
----> header.scss
----> body.scss
----> footer.scss
```

т.е. в папке `scss` лежат 4 `.scss` файла. И я пытаюсь сделать из них бандл `app.css`,  но не получается.

Соответственно в `webpack.mix.js` пробовал сделать так:

```js
mix.sass(
    [
        './src/scss/root.scss',
        './src/scss/header.scss',
        './src/scss/body.scss',
        './src/scss/footer.scss'
    ], './dist/app.css'
)
```

но получаю ошибку

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.sass() is missing required parameter 1: src

И так тоже делал:

```js
mix.sass('./src/scss/root.scss', './dist/app.css')
   .sass('./src/scss/header.scss', './dist/app.css')
   .sass('./src/scss/body.scss', './dist/app.css')
   .sass('./src/scss/footer.scss', './dist/app.css');
```

Но так он записывает в `app.css` только из `footer.scss` `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**Как правильно сделать бандл из .sass файлов в laravel-mix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединять sass в один можно с помощью правила [@import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) или правила [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Для начала надо создать общий файл `.scss`, в который подключаются все модули. Именно этот файл и надо конвертировать в `.css`.

Comment: Дополнить один момент: Если у вас есть как у меня "root.scss" в котором есть :root, наследуемые шаблоны и прочее то надо использовать @import, при использовании `@use` он не видит то что в родительских файлах и соответственно  `@extend` не сработает если шаблон в родительском файле